# LTSpice component attribute editor problem

Tags: ltspice

I have a problem in LTSpice with calling "component attribute" on both versions IV and XVII.
Normally you should be able to call the component attribute window by pressing Ctrl+RightClick on the component (for example a Diode). Then you can enter the values that are not within LTSpice library. 
[image: Component Attribute window]

But sometimes this short-key doesn't work on my computer which is running windows 10 X86. There is also no menu for it.
Does anybody face this problem and knows how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by running the LTSpie as administrator. 
Because my windows 10 user account is not the administrator, therefore, it has not administrative privileges, as a result, can not run the editing mode.
Whenever I didn't open the software as administrator, the software also couldn't run "Component attribute editor" which is kind of editing the components.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me: whatever edit of component's attributes there is from *within* the LTspice schematic editor doesn't affect the way they are saved on the disk, because adding another component from the database will reveal the same default parameters, unedited, which can be edited anyway you like. Same for adding any new element from the database in any new schematic, whether in the same instance of LTspice or others. Maybe you just had the `Ctrl` key "stuck", somehow, it happens to me sometimes (old laptop). Sometimes I have to hit the key a few times, "shock" it, to work.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Thanks for your comment. Since I am using an almost new laptop(2013) and also tested it by right Ctrl key when the left one doesn't work, probably it is not related to the Ctrl key. But I will consider your idea during next uses and will mention here if I found something.

Comment: Then how is a third party model imported without admin privileges?

Comment: Got the same problem when running as admin. This does not fix it.